# Invalid Alphanumeric 'From' address with Twilio SMS

Tags: sms, twilio, alphanumeric

I am trying to [send an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) with Twilio using the alphanumeric 'from' address. I'm in Australia, sending to an Australian mobile number. My cURL request looks like this:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<Account SID>/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+614XXXXXXXX'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=Test'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Test' \
-u <Account SID>:<Auth Token>
```

The response I am receiving is:

```
{
    "code": 21212, 
    "message": "The 'From' number Test is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.", 
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21212", 
    "status": 400
}
```

I've tried a number of different alphanumeric sender IDs and none have been successful. My sender ID does appear to meet the `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` with max length 11 and at least 1 alpha character requirement. I've double checked my Account SID and Auth Token as well as the ability to send Alphanumeric SMS within Australia. I've also verified I'm not accidentally using my Test code incase that would have any effect. My account also does have credit on it.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're doing everything right for sending a message using an alphanumeric sender ID. However, in order to [get your account setup for sending these messages](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-alphanumeric-sender-id-and-how-do-i-get-started) you need to [contact support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and request your account is enabled to use alphanumeric sender IDs.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: We have got the permission fromTwilio but still unable to send Message using Alphanumeric ID. Can you please suggest what else we can do in this case?

Comment: @jitendra I'd like to help, but I need to see your code. Or, is it possible that you are trying to send messages using an alpha ID to a country that doesn't support it?

Comment: Thanx for your valuable reply. I was trying to use Alphanumeric for US and India. For the US I found  it doesn't support. But for India, it supports but it need registration. I want to know that what is this extra permission/registration on Country Level and How can we get it?

Comment: If you need to register then get in touch with help@twilio.com and they can help you out.